# Unrealistically large values in SMART

Tags: ubuntu, ssd, smart

Recently ubuntu said me that my SSD is doomed. This computer has been working for about 10 years including about 4 years with this particular ssd. This message appeared after waking from standby mode.

Smartctl says this:

```
18:31:21 j0 wormball@wormball-desktop:~$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-76-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Indilinx Barefoot 3 based SSDs
Device Model:     OCZ-VERTEX460A
Serial Number:    A22MQ061448001675
LU WWN Device Id: 5 e83a97 10001f987
Firmware Version: 1.01
User Capacity:    120 034 123 776 bytes [120 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri Mar 20 18:31:22 2020 MSK
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
Drive failure expected in less than 24 hours. SAVE ALL DATA.
No failed Attributes found.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x1d) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Abort Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    No Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x00) Error logging NOT supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   0) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   0) minutes.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 18
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0000   218   218   000    Old_age   Offline      -       94918362
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       7194967 (0 0 87)
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       622704117
171 Avail_OP_Block_Count    0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
174 Pwr_Cycle_Ct_Unplanned  0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
195 Total_Prog_Failures     0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       2316479378
196 Total_Erase_Failures    0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       3690435914
197 Total_Unc_Read_Failures 0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       2677937662
208 Average_Erase_Count     0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       891
210 SATA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
224 In_Warranty             0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
225 DAS_Polarity            0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
233 Remaining_Lifetime_Perc 0x0000   071   071   000    Old_age   Offline      -       71
241 Host_Writes_GiB         0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       6493436533484
242 Host_Reads_GiB          0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1340587272588
249 Total_NAND_Prog_Ct_GiB  0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       175167090378392

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

Warning! SMART Self-Test Log Structure error: invalid SMART checksum.
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported

18:31:22 j0 wormball@wormball-desktop:~$ uname -a
Linux wormball-desktop 4.15.0-76-generic #86-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 17 17:24:28 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

As you can see, my ssd should have been working for 821 years, store 159 zebibytes (with speed of 6762 gib/s) and die for about a hundred times. However all works fine and only for about 4 years.

Why is it so and what should i do?

UPD: It actually died several days later.

UPD2: It resurrected another several days later and is feeling like a newborn.

```
22:19:44 j0 wormball@wormball-desktop:~$ sudo smartctl /dev/sdc
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-91-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

ATA device successfully opened

Use 'smartctl -a' (or '-x') to print SMART (and more) information

22:20:12 j0 wormball@wormball-desktop:~$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdc
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-91-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Indilinx Barefoot 3 based SSDs
Device Model:     OCZ-VERTEX460A
Serial Number:    A22MQ061448001675
LU WWN Device Id: 5 e83a97 10001f987
Firmware Version: 1.01
User Capacity:    120 034 123 776 bytes [120 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Mar 30 22:20:18 2020 MSK
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x1d) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Abort Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    No Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x00) Error logging NOT supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   0) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   0) minutes.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 18
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0000   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1
171 Avail_OP_Block_Count    0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       45003856
174 Pwr_Cycle_Ct_Unplanned  0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1
195 Total_Prog_Failures     0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
196 Total_Erase_Failures    0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
197 Total_Unc_Read_Failures 0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
208 Average_Erase_Count     0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       894
210 SATA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
224 In_Warranty             0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1
225 DAS_Polarity            0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
233 Remaining_Lifetime_Perc 0x0000   071   071   000    Old_age   Offline      -       71
241 Host_Writes_GiB         0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
242 Host_Reads_GiB          0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
249 Total_NAND_Prog_Ct_GiB  0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       13

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

Warning! SMART Self-Test Log Structure error: invalid SMART checksum.
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported

22:20:18 j0 wormball@wormball-desktop:~$ sudo badblocks -v /dev/sdc5 > shit/badsectors.txt
Checking blocks 0 to 100443135
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): ^C

Interrupted at block 32612544
22:24:02 j0 wormball@wormball-desktop:~$ sudo badblocks -vn /dev/sdc5 > shit/badsectors.txt
Checking for bad blocks in non-destructive read-write mode
From block 0 to 100443135
Testing with random pattern: Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)
```

Comment: People have reported "interesting" SMART results from OCZ Vertex SSDs, including weird values on a drive that works fine. Note that RAW values are usually in hex, and despite the name (e.g. Power_On_**Hours**) the actual measurement unit depends on the manufacturer and may be something else such as ten-minute intervals or less. Try Googling "OCZ Vertex SMART values" to see what I mean.

Comment: Where do you see such strange values? To me everything looks fine: 100 normally means no data. Remaining Lifetime Percent is 71%, so you should be fine for 9 more years according to my calculations.

Comment: Some manufacturers encode a couple values into one field so high numbers are really two 32-bit numbers displayed as a single 64-bit (or 2x16 displayed as one 32). So you really have to check the manufacturer's specs.

Comment: harrymc Scroll right.

Comment: @xenoid Yes, but i checked smart many times before, and i saw perfectly normal values, including 0 reallocated sectors. I have never updated ssd firmware. I updated ubuntu more than month ago, and all was fine.